# Каким образом функция http.ServeFile становится потенциально опасной

Tags: golang

```
http.ServeFile(w, r, "/var/www/static/"+req.URL.Path)
```

Что плохого может случиться, если использовать эту функцию для отдача статики? В документации понял не всё, но уяснил и проверил, что при вводе двух точек(..) Функция перенаправляет на главную. Как обеспечить безопасность, то есть на какие символы фильтровать req.URL.Path ?

[ссылка на функцию](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeFile)

Comment: Есть причина, по которой вы не хотите использовать [`http.FileServer`](https://tip.golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer), который всё автомагически сделает за вас?

Comment: Если честно, я не знаю как его встроить в свой код, при встраивании мои обработчики перестают работать(не использую HundleFunc, написал свои)

Comment: Напишите, как вы регистрируете обработчики, и я постараюсь показать вам, как использовать `http.FileServer`.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/P2co4G1K-xW

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/9Vu2mJHtopj (пакет registr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Крайне не рекомендую вам делать доморощенные роутеры на регекспах. Лучше используйте `github.com/gorilla/mux`. В вашем случае, если вы хотите показывать файлы например на `example.com/public/...`, можете сделать что-то вроде:

```golang
publicHandler := http.StripPrefix("/public/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("/var/www/static/")))
register.Get("/public/", false, publicHandler.ServeHTTP)
```

Comment: не могли бы вы объяснить что с "доморощеннами роутерами на регекспах"  не так?

Comment: Скорость ниже, поддержка труднее, брать параметры из пути (а-ля `/users/42/profile`) сложнее. Не поймите неправильно, я тоже таким увлекался, когда только начинал. Потом надоело.

Comment: Понял. Благодарю. Вот и я начинаю по вашему пути. Пока не надоело )